# Google App Script, highlight new users since last month

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I made a little function to retrieve the users we have on Google Workspace, and made a cron for this list to be refreshed once a month.

What I'd like to do now is to highlight cells of the new users created last month, but I didn't find a proper way to do it yet.

ie. next execution planned will be the 1st of June, I would need all accounts created in May to be highlighted

Any hint ?

My current code looks like this :

```html
function listAllUsers() {

 var sh = '-- my sheet id --';
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sh);
 var sheet1 = sheet.getSheetByName('sheet title');
  
  var sheet1range = sheet.getRange("A:H")
  sheet1range.clear()
 
  var data = [];
  data.push(['Email' ,'First Name', 'Last Name',  'Suspended', 'Last Login Time','Creation', '2FA Active', 'Is admin']);
  var pageToken, page;
  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
    
      domain: '-- my domain --',
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    var users = page.users;
    if (users) {
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
        data.push([user.primaryEmail, user.name.givenName, user.name.familyName, user.suspended, user.lastLoginTime , user.creationTime, user.isEnrolledIn2Sv, user.isAdmin ]);
      }
    } else {
    Logger.log('No users found.');
       }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  
  sheet1.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
  var dated = sheet.getRange("P1")
  dated.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),'dd-MMM-yyy'));
  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- Your Spreadsheet has the 1st header row and the data rows. The column "F" has the value of the created time of the user account.
- You want to set the background color of the cells (columns "A" to "H") of the specific month for the column "F".
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

#### Sample script:

```js
function sample() {
  var checkYear = 2022; // Please set year.
  var checkMonth = 5; // Please set month. This sample is May.
  var color = "red"; // Please set the color you want to set.

  var sh = '-- my sheet id --';
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sh);
  var sheet1 = sheet.getSheetByName('sheet title');

  var range = sheet1.getRange("A2:H" + sheet1.getLastRow());
  var backgrounds = range.getValues().map(r => Array(r.length).fill(r[5].getFullYear() == checkYear && r[5].getMonth() == checkMonth - 1 ? color : null));
  range.setBackgrounds(backgrounds);
}
```

- When this script is run, by checking the values of column "F", the background color of columns "A" to "H" is changed to "red" color.
- When you want to include this script in your showing script, how about the following modification? In this case, please add the following script to the bottom of your function.

  ```
    var checkYear = 2022; // Please set year.
    var checkMonth = 5; // Please set month. This sample is May.
    var color = "red"; // Please set the color you want to set.

    var range = sheet1.getRange("A2:H" + sheet1.getLastRow());
    var backgrounds = range.getValues().map(r => Array(r.length).fill(r[5].getFullYear() == checkYear && r[5].getMonth() == checkMonth - 1 ? color : null));
    range.setBackgrounds(backgrounds);
  ```

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [setBackgrounds(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundscolor)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> Thanks for the hint ! You basically got the idea, but there's still need to do some manual settings in your example. As I want to run this script in a crontab and not care about it anymore, I would need to skip the checkYear and checkMonth config part. Is there any way to define these two vars automatically ?

If you want to set the background color of cells by this month, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function sample() {
  var color = "red"; // Please set the color you want to set.

  var date = new Date();
  var checkYear = date.getFullYear();
  var checkMonth = date.getMonth();

  var sh = '-- my sheet id --';
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sh);
  var sheet1 = sheet.getSheetByName('sheet title');
 
  var range = sheet1.getRange("A2:H" + sheet1.getLastRow());
  var backgrounds = range.getValues().map(r => {
    if (r[5]) {
      var d = new Date(r[5]);
      return Array(r.length).fill(d.getFullYear() == checkYear && d.getMonth() == checkMonth ? color : null)
    }
    return Array(r.length).fill(null);
  });
  range.setBackgrounds(backgrounds);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint ! You basically got the idea, but there's still need to do some manual settings in your example. As I want to run this script in a crontab and not care about it anymore, I would need to skip the checkYear and checkMonth config part. Is there any way to define these two vars automatically ?

Comment: @SBO Thank you for replying. From your reply, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? In the added script, the background color of cells is set by this month.

Comment: Just tried it, and I have the following output : TypeError: r[5].getFullYear is not a function

Comment: @SBO Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `Just tried it, and I have the following output : TypeError: r[5].getFullYear is not a function`, from your showing script, I had thought that the values after 2nd row have the correct values. But, unfortunately, I have no information about your actual Spreadsheet. So, by guessing your Spreadsheet, I modified the sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: No need to apologize, it's already kind to help me solve this :) No more errors during the execution, but no color change. The creation date for each user is stored in column F, with for example this kind of data : 2022-04-08T09:42:25.000Z

Comment: @SBO Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I had thought that the values of column "F" is the date object. But from `2022-04-08T09:42:25.000Z`, it seems that it was the string value. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. For this, I upadted the sample script. Could you please confirm it?